# Render shape in a view

Tags: orchardcms

I've created ContentType `Product` with `ProductPart`, but since html of the product is rather complex I decided to use one view **Content-Product.cshtml** and render all the part information manually instead of using shapes. But I still need to render one shape for price, because I need to format it through service and I'd like to do that in a `ProductPart` driver.

I tried to define new **zone** in this view and use **placement.info** to place the shape. All it does is that it renders shape's type name instead of html.

```
Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes.Shape
```

Can I even use this approach to insert shape? Or should I choose different approach?

**Driver:**

```
protected override DriverResult Display(ProductPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    return ContentShape("Parts_Product_Price",
    () => shapeHelper.Parts_Product_Price(
        ContentPart: part,
        ContentItem: part.ContentItem));
}
```

**Content-Product.cshtml:**

```
@Model.PriceZone()
```

**Placement.info:**

```
<Place Parts_Product_Price="PriceZone:1"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Content-Product.cshtml view you want this instead:

```
@Display(Model.PriceZone)
```

Comment: Ah ha! Zone is a shape too! Thanks :D

Comment: Yeah, in an Item Template you have "content zones", which are just shapes with a list of shapes to render :) I wrote a small blog post on item templates, though it's quite high level and you probably know everything it covers, but it might help someone... maybe http://arkleseizure.net/what-the-hell-is-an-item-template